Jenkins ECS build agent fails at pulling jenkins/inbound-agent:latest image
I have launced an Ec2 instance and installed jenkins there. I want to use ecs build agents and have configured all the setting properly. When I start the job from Jenkins, I get this error:
Task stopped at: 2024-05-28T00:41:41.949Z
CannotPullContainerError: pull image manifest has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref docker.io/jenkins/inbound-agent:latest: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/jenkins/inbound-agent/manifests/latest": dial tcp 54.198.86.24:443: i/o timeout
However if I run the task manually in the aws cluster using the task Definition created by the jenkins job, the task gets started and able to run.
What configuration am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.
Would be a great help if someone could explain me what VPC,subnet, NAT gate way are required?
Note: I'm trying this on the free tier account.
